# How to prove "reboot -f" command is blocking?

Tags: linux, shell

While writing shell script for an embedded Linux device, my colleges tends to add a infinite loop after `reboot` / `reboot -f` command to make sure the later part of the script won't run during reboot. However I wonder whether `reboot -f` is actually a blocking command or not.

I tried `reboot; touch test` and `test` is created. Thus a normal `reboot` should be non-blocking. However, running `reboot -f ; touch test` command won't create `test`. Some may argue that `touch` or the shell might have been killed before touch` can execute so it is not a sufficient proof.

The `reboot` is actually sym-link to sysvinit's `halt` executable.

May someone gives a proof or an explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your OS, `reboot` can be very different. For me, `reboot` is a symlink to systemctl:

```
ls -la /sbin/reboot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 maj  3 13:30 /sbin/reboot -> /bin/systemctl
```

In this case, it is equivalent to `systemctl reboot` which is equivalent to `systemctl start reboot.target --job-mode=replace-irreversibly --no-block` (see manpage of systemctl).

`-force` will in this case just speed up the process of rebooting, probably resulting in the shell being killed before the file was touched.
If you want this to be blocking, you could try something like `systemctl start reboot.target --job-mode=replace-irreversibly`. But I'm not sure if a blocking reboot can be achieved like this.

If you are on a non-systemd environment, `reboot` might work differently for you, though.

I think, an infinite loop is not the cleanest solution here, you could just do `exit` after the reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your information. The `reboot` of my OS is a symlink to `/sbin/halt` which is built from sysvinit2.88. I may need to dig into the code to find out the answer. And for exit the script it depends on the situation. In my case the script is called by `/etc/init.d/rcS` so exit the script will make `rcS` run the next script file.